# Is MQ Fastpath is default in JMS connector

Tags: jms, mule, ibm-mq, spring-jms, mule-esb

I am connecting to MQ-9.x using Mule JMS connector and recent days i observed that queue manager going down frequently and it says FAST path application has ended error at QM logs, also no OPPROCS connections are reducing even i brought down my Mule engine.  As a workaround, I am rebooting my queue manager instance :(

So now my question is whether IBM JMS client jar contains Fastpath binding connection is default or its been handled in Mule itself [i don't think so] and no code written to handle this.

Maven dependencies

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.ibm.mq</groupId>
    <artifactId>com.ibm.mq.allclient</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.jms-api</artifactId>
    <version>RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

QM.INI

```
#*******************************************************************#
#* Module Name: qm.ini                                             *#
#* Type       : WebSphere MQ queue manager configuration file      *#
#  Function   : Define the configuration of a single queue manager *#
#*                                                                 *#
#*******************************************************************#
#* Notes      :                                                    *#
#* 1) This file defines the configuration of the queue manager     *#
#*                                                                 *#
#*******************************************************************#
ExitPath:
   ExitsDefaultPath=/var/mqm/exits
   ExitsDefaultPath64=/var/mqm/exits64
#*                                                                 *#
#*                                                                 *#
Log:
   LogPrimaryFiles=5
   LogSecondaryFiles=2
   LogFilePages=1024
   LogType=CIRCULAR
   LogBufferPages=0
   LogPath=/mqha/Local/log/XXXXX/XXXXX/
   LogWriteIntegrity=TripleWrite
Service:
   Name=AuthorizationService
   EntryPoints=14
ServiceComponent:
   Service=XXXXXService
   Name=XXXXXX.service
   Module=amqzfu
   ComponentDataSize=0
TCP:
   SndBuffSize=0
   RcvBuffSize=0
   RcvSndBuffSize=0
   RcvRcvBuffSize=0
   ClntSndBuffSize=0
   ClntRcvBuffSize=0
   SvrSndBuffSize=0
   SvrRcvBuffSize=0
```

Error log

```
Probe Severity    :- 3                                                      |
| Probe Description :- AMQ7159W: A FASTPATH application has ended             |
|   unexpectedly
```

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Check your `qm.ini` file for and fastpath related settings.

Comment: Josh - Added the QM.INI in my post.  Not sure which one to be referred w.r.to Fastpath setting in QM level.

Comment: @JoshMc - updated the QM.INI.

Comment: Can you add a little more of the FDC that you have seen (the "Error log" in your post). So we can see the whole header (the boxed area).

Comment: How does Mule connect to the queue manager?  Does Mule run on the same server as the queue manager?  If so does it connect in "binding" mode?  If not running on the same server it would connect in client mode, if running on the same server it could connect in client mode.  JMS apps that connect local in binding mode can specify `CONNOPT` of `FASTPATH`, but not when making a client connection.  When making a client connection the queue manager can be configured to use `FASTPATH` for channels by setting the `qm.ini` `channels` stanza `MQIBindType=FASTPATH` which you do not have.

Comment: @JoshMc - its my bad, posted the old QM.INI.  Yes fastpath enabled in it as  MQIBindType=FASTPATH.  From your comments, i am concluding JMS cannot connect as Fastpath binding by default where it can be done by setting up in the QM.ini is the only option if we are connecting as a client.

Comment: That is correct for any MQ client type.